# Modify Twitter login text on Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I used the TwitterLoginButton provided by Fabric, it has a login UI like this:

[image]

How can I change the the text that says:

> Authorise Created by Fabric for (username)-projects:(package name) on android to use your account.

To my real app name, but not package and Fabric username?

Thank you!

Comment: That should have been done when registering your app... Also you need to have the correct accounts. More here ***http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-authentication-with-twitter-and-fabric--cms-23801***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be changed on the website Fabric.io. After login, select the correct project from the top let corner, and then you will see an "Edit" link which let you modify the project name